# Getting numerator and denominator of a fraction in R

Tags: r, fractions

Using the function `fractions` in the library MASS, I can convert a decimal to a fraction:

```
> fractions(.375)
  [1] 3/8
```

But then how to I extract the numerator and denominator? The help for `fractions` mentions an attribute "fracs", but I can't seem to access it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A character representation of the fraction is stored in an attribute:

```
x <- fractions(0.175)
> strsplit(attr(x,"fracs"),"/")
[[1]]
[1] "7"  "40"
```

Comment: @BonnieScott Well, as juba demonstrated, it's pretty easy to write your own function to pull them out with.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `fracs` attribute from your fraction object the following way, but it is just the character representation of your fraction :

```
x <- fractions(.375)
attr(x, "fracs")
# [1] "3/8"
```

If you want to access numerator and denominator values, you can just split the string with the following function :

```
getfracs <- function(frac) {
  tmp <- strsplit(attr(frac,"fracs"), "/")[[1]]
  list(numerator=as.numeric(tmp[1]),denominator=as.numeric(tmp[2]))
}
```

Which you can use this way :

```
fracs <- getfracs(x)
fracs$numerator
# [1] 3
fracs$denominator
# [1] 8
```